# TypeError: Cannot set property 'firstData' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, expression

IM getting two errors in my service. They are both the same errors. IM going to post my service and my controller.

This is my service:

```
 getData: function (dataRecievedCallback, schemeid, userid) {

            //Average JSON api
            averageData = function () {
                return $http.get(first.json)
            }


            //User JSON api
            userData = function () {
                return $http.get(second.json)

            }
```

And here is my controller:

```
 serviceName.averageData().then(function (response) {
                $scope.firstData = response.data;
            });


           serviceName.userData().then(function (response) {
                $scope.secondData = response.data;
            });
```

I dont want to elaborate my data I want to display it as it is. In my html I have an ng-repeat, how can I add both in my expression?

Comment: Looks like $scope isn't set, where is that variable coming from?

Comment: I have a getData function and $scope is on of the parameters.

Comment: you should not have `$scope` in your service, you should return the promise to the controller and then use the response

Comment: You need to inject your service in your controller in order to use it.
The service has no refrence to the $scope

Comment: How can I do that. Sorry but im new to coding. I removed $scope from the service.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to show how this should be set up:

Service:

```
methodName: function() {
  return $http.get(first.json);
}
```

Controller:

```
ServiceName.methodName().then(function(response) {
    $scope.firstData = response.data;
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error); // See the error in console if any
  });
```

Comment: doesnt seem to be working, Im not getting any error message

Comment: I edited my code and im getting the error "servicename.averageData is not a function"

Comment: do you have the service? and have you injected it into your controller?

Comment: Yes, I know how to load one json file but i never had to load two of them

Comment: you can create another method in your service `return $http.get(second.json)` and then call it from you controller like the first one